# Question about quartic congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to follow an argument that I don't understand. Let $p$ be an odd prime. Suppose $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime integers such that $p$ does not divide $x$ and $x^4 \equiv 17y^4$ (mod $p$). Then 17 is a square mod $p$. Why is this?

My attempt was to write out the definition: there exists an integer $m$ such that $pm=x^4-17y^4$. We want to show that there is an integer $l$ such that $p$ divides $l^2-17$. I tried factoring $x^4-17y^4$ but I don't think that will lead to anything because the factored terms might be irrational.

Comment: You meant $x, z$?  But if $z$ is a non-zero residue $\pmod p$ then your congruence implies $(xz^{-1})^4\equiv 17\pmod p$ so you can see an explicit square root.  Can you eliminate the case $z\equiv 0 \pmod p$?

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to include some necessary hypotheses. It is fixed.

Comment: Well, that's one way to rule out the zero case, but it wasn't necessary.  if $p$ did divide $y$ then your congruence would tell us that $p$ also divided $x$, in contradiction of relative primality.

Comment: OK, I edited it again. I'm still stuck though.

Comment: I gave you the solution in my first comment!

Comment: What I don't understand is that $x^2/y^2$ may not be an integer. What I have is that there is an integer $m$ such that $pm/z^4 = (x^2/z^2)^2-17$.

Comment: That's not what I meant.  Any non-zero residue ($y$ in your new notation) has a unique inverse $\pmod p$, which I will denote by $y^{-1}$.  That is not the same as $\frac 1y$.

Comment: Let's do an explicit example.  $p=19$.  You can check that $4^4\equiv 17*3^4\pmod {19}$.  Now, the inverse of $3$ $\pmod {19}$ is $13$, as $3*13=39\equiv 1 \pmod {19}$.  Thus we ought to have $(4*13)^4\equiv 17 \pmod {19}$.  But it is easily checked that $4*13\equiv -5 \pmod {19}$ and, indeed, $(-5)^4\equiv 17 \pmod {19}$.

Comment: Oh! I see. Let me clarify: We have $x^4-17z^4=0$ in the field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Since $z$ is not 0, we can multiply each side of the expression by $(z^{-1})^4$ to get $(xz^{-1})^4-17=0$ in $F_p$. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the symbol of Legendre. You have $$\left(\frac{17y^4}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{x^4}{p}\right)=1$$ obviously because $x^4\ne 0$ ($p$ does not divide $x$) is a square. Now by the multiplicativity property you have
$$\left(\frac{17y^4}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{17}{p}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{y^4}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{17}{p}\right)\cdot 1=1 $$ which means $17$ is a square modulo $p$.